# @hapi/bell (discord) --> @hapi/cookie authentication handoff

Tags: cookies, oauth, hapi

I'm building a hapi(v18.4.0) API that I want to authenticate users against the Discord OAuth2 service.  I'm using @hapi/bell(v11.1.0) to handle the OAuth2 handshaking.

I'm able to authenticate via Discord but I can not get @hapi/cookie(v10.1.2) to take over authentication responsibilities.  I can see the cookie is being created but the only time I see the cookie validateFunc function called is with the 'logout' route.  I believe I've set all the necessary flags for developing on localhost.

Basically I can't get the cookie auth strategy to work.  And I'm surprised I don't see the validateFunc called when I go to routes that require authentication.

Below are my authentication strategy setups, cookie validateFunc function, login/logout routes, and test routes.

Thanks for the help!

```
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'auth',
  dependencies: ['hapi-mongodb', 'bell', '@hapi/cookie'],
  register: (server, options) => {

    server.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', {
      cookie: {
        name: 'sid-demo',
        password: SECRET_KEY,
        isSecure: false,
        isSameSite: 'Lax'
      },
      redirectTo: '/demo-server/api/v1/auth/login', //If there is no session, redirect here
      validateFunc: async (request, session) => {

        console.log("validating cookie...");
        const db = request.mongo.db;
        const ObjectID = request.mongo.ObjectID;

        try {
          const user = await db.collection(usersTable).findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(session.id) });
          if (!user) {
            console.log("no user found, cookie invalid");
            return { valid: false };
          }

          return { valid: true, credentials: user };

        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log("Validation error:", err);
          return { valid: false };        
        }
      }
    });

    server.auth.strategy('discord', 'bell', {
      provider: 'discord',
      password: SECRET_KEY,
      clientId: DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: DISCORD_SECRET,
      isSecure: false,
      isSameSite: 'Lax'
    });
  }
};
```

```
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'routes-auth',
  dependencies: ['hapi-mongodb', 'auth'],
  register: (server, options) => {

    server.auth.default('session');

    server.route({
      method: ['GET', 'POST'],
      path: '/demo-server/api/v1/auth/login',
      options: {
        auth: 'discord',
        handler: async (request, h) => {

          if (!request.auth.isAuthenticated) {
            console.log("authenticaion failed");
            return `Authentication failed due to: ${request.auth.error.message}`;
          }

          const db = request.mongo.db;

          const credentials = request.auth.credentials;
          const profile = request.auth.credentials.profile;

          try {
            const result = await db.collection(usersTable).findOne({ email: request.auth.credentials.profile.email });
            if (result) {

              console.log("user exists");

              request.cookieAuth.set({
                id: result.id,
                username: profile.username,
                token: credentials.token
              });

              return h.redirect('/demo-server/restricted');
            }
          }
          catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return Boom.serverUnavailable('database error');
          }

          console.log("user does not exists, registering new user");
          const user = {
            email: request.auth.credentials.profile.email,
            last_login: new Date(),
            username: request.auth.credentials.profile.username,
          };

          try {

            const result = await db.collection(usersTable).insertOne(user);

            request.cookieAuth.set({
              id: result.insertedId,
              username: profile.username,
              token: credentials.token
            });

          }
          catch (err) {
            return Boom.serverUnavailable('database error');
          }

          return h.redirect('/demo-server/restricted');

        },
        tags: ['auth', 'api']
      }
    });

    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/demo-server/api/v1/auth/logout',
      options: {
        handler: (request, h) => {

          request.cookieAuth.clear();
          return h.redirect('/demo-server');
        }
      }
    });
```

```
exports.plugin = {
  name: 'routes-default',
  dependencies: ['auth'],
  register: (server, options) => {

    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/demo-server',
      handler: (request, h) => {

        return h.response({ result: 'Welcome to demo-server!' }).code(200);
      },
      config: {
        description: 'This is default route for the API.',
        response: {
          status: {}
        },
        tags: ['default','test']
      }
    });

    server.route({
      method: 'GET',
      path: '/demo-server/restricted',
      handler: (request, h) => {

        return h.response({ message: 'Ok, You are authorized.' }).code(200);

      },
      config: {
        auth: {
          mode: 'try'
        },
        description: 'This is a default route used for testing the jwt authentication.',
        response: {
          status: {}
        },
        tags: ['default','test','auth']
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue...
I needed to set the path to the root of the API.

```
cookie: {
        name: 'sid-demo',
        password: SECRET_KEY, //Use something more secure in production
        path: '/demo-server', // <--- This was what fixed the issue
        isSecure: false,
        isSameSite: 'Lax'
      },
```